# How to eliminate duplicate data after fetching api response and stored in coredata then display in UItableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, duplicates

***I parsed the Api and stored in CoreData but when i display the results in UITableView its displaying the image, name and email twice. How to eliminate the duplicate and display only unique data. I also added a constraint and "context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy which stopped the merging of data after each run but now its displaying all the data twice."***

**Any help Will be highly appreciable**

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textAge: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let database = DatabaseHandle.shared
    var users: [User]?{
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //tableView.register(UserTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserTableViewCell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        users = database.fetch(User.self)
        
        //print(users)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        ApiHandler.shared.syncUser {
            self.users = self.database.fetch(User.self)
        }
    }
    
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UserTableViewCell
        
        cell.user = users?[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let user = users?[indexPath.row] else {return}
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.database.delete(object: user)
        users?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
}
```

**ApiHandler **

```
import UIKit

class ApiHandler{
    
    static let shared = ApiHandler()
    
    func syncUser(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)){
        var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")!)
        req.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: { data,response,error -> Void in
            print(response!)
            
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary <String,AnyObject>
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse<[UserServerModel]>.self, from: data!)
                model.data.forEach({$0.store()})
                print(json)
                completion()
            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion()
            }
            
            
        })
        task.resume()
        
    }
}

public struct ApiResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    public let total_pages: Int
    public let per_page: Int
    public let data: T
    public let page: Int
    public let total: Int
    
}
```

**DatabaseHandle**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DatabaseHandle{
    
    private var viewContext:NSManagedObjectContext
    static let shared = DatabaseHandle()
    init() {
        viewContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    func add<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type: T.Type)-> T?{
        guard let entityName = T.entity().name else {return nil}
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: viewContext) else{return nil}
        let object = T(entity: entity, insertInto: viewContext)
        return object
        }
    
    func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(_ type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        let request = T.fetchRequest()
        do{
            let result = try viewContext.fetch(request)
            
            return result as! [T]
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
        
    }
    
    func save(){
        do{
            try viewContext.save()
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T:NSManagedObject>(object: T){
        viewContext.delete(object)
        save()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're calling

```
model.data.forEach({$0.store()})
```

I'm not sure if store is a custom function, but perhaps you're not first checking if it already exists in coredata, so you end up just saving it twice.

Comment: yes store is a custom function.    ```import Foundation

struct UserServerModel:Codable {
    var avatar: String
    var email: String
    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String
    var id: Int
    
    static let database = DatabaseHandle.shared
    
    func store(){
        guard let user = UserServerModel.database.add(User.self) else {return}
        user.avatar = avatar
        user.email = email
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.id = Int16(id)
        UserServerModel.database.save()
    }
    
}  ```

Comment: why are you adding the user in the guard statement?

Comment: Unless i use guard statment in user i have to unwrapp ```user.avatar = avatar         user.email = email         user.first_name = first_name         user.last_name = last_name         user.id = Int16(id)```

Comment: somewhere i have to add a condition to check duplicate element and delete that before stores in coredata i don't want to maintain redundant data then filter later while fetching.

Comment: Not checking for duplicates before you add, sounds like the source of your problem.

Comment: Here i need help where i suppose to add the condition?

Comment: Up to you- Personally I would add it in the store function, because adding it into the add function gives it too many responsibilities. The add should be a result of the nil check being true

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned you need to check the persistence layer for the existence of records before adding a new one. I'd suggest implementing a protocol so that your other API data structures can be persisted as well.

```
protocol Persistable {
    associatedtype Persisted: NSManagedObject
    var predicate: NSPredicate? { get }
    func persist(into object: Persisted)
}

extension NSPredicate {
    static func userId(equalTo id: Int16) -> NSPredicate {
        return .init(format: "id == %d", id)
    }
}

extension UserServerModel: Persistable {

    var predicate: NSPredicate? { .userId(equalTo: Int16(self.id)) }

    func persist(into object: User) {
        object.avatar = avatar
        object.email = email
        object.first_name = first_name
        object.last_name = last_name
        object.id = Int16(id)
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of mixing repository logic with my models so I'd create some sort of a bridge between your API and persistence models.

```
enum PersistenceBridge {

    @discardableResult
    static func updateOrCreate<T: Persistable>(model: T) -> T.Persisted? {
        return update(model: model) ?? create(model: model)
    }

    @discardableResult
    static func update<T: Persistable>(model: T) -> T.Persisted? {
        let object = DatabaseHandle.shared.fetch(T.Persisted.self, predicate: model.predicate).first
        return persist(model: model, into: object)
    }

    @discardableResult
    static func create<T: Persistable>(model: T) -> T.Persisted? {
        let object = DatabaseHandle.shared.add(T.Persisted.self)
        return persist(model: model, into: object)
    }

    static func persist<T: Persistable>(model: T, into object: T.Persisted?) -> T.Persisted? {
        if let object = object { model.persist(into: object) }
        return object
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a predicate parameter to your fetch method so you can constrain your results:

```
extension DatabaseHandle {

    func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(_ type: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [T] {
        let request = T.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = predicate
        do{
            let result = try viewContext.fetch(request)

            return result as! [T]
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, add some persistence logic to your ApiHandler and you're good to go:

```
extension ApiHandler {
    func persist<T: Persistable>(response: ApiResponse<[T]>) {
        response.data.forEach {
            PersistenceBridge.updateOrCreate(model: $0)
        }
    }
}
```